# Vim: ignore case in "f" and "t" motion commands

Tags: vim

Vim `:set ignorecase` command do not affect "f" and "t" motion commands in my vim config.

Is there any option or hack that makes this commands to ignore case?

Comment: See also the Q/A on vi.SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/how-to-make-fchar-case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like:

```
function! ForwardLookup()
    " get next key pressed
    let c = nr2char(getchar())
    let old_search_pattern = @/
    " Use of \V enables very-nonmagic pattern
    exec 'normal /\c\V' . escape(c, '\/') . nr2char(0x0d)
    let @/ = old_search_pattern
endfunction
nnoremap f :call ForwardLookup()<CR>
```

Comment: Not strong enough: don't support numeric prefix, goes over line break, no visual mode support.

Comment: This also doesn't support repeat f command by `;`

Answer (score 0):

A basic version of this is actually in the reference manual as an example of how to use the `getchar()` function:

> This example redefines "f" to ignore case:
>
> ```
> :nmap f :call FindChar()<CR>
> :function FindChar()
> :  let c = nr2char(getchar())
> :  while col('.') < col('$') - 1
> :    normal l
> :    if getline('.')[col('.') - 1] ==? c
> :      break
> :    endif
> :  endwhile
> :endfunction
> ```

See `:help getchar()`.

You'll need to save the character returned and write a similar map for <kbd>;</kbd> if you want that to work too, and write code to handle `v:count1` if you want it to work with counts.